# How to develop a web browser using c# .net using installed.net libraries and without using the web browser control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webbrowser-control, windowsformshost

I have searched the internet for 2 days having found no answer to the below requirement. What i found most were GeckoFX and CefSharp which are external packages and not installed libraries. How can this be done?

I have been asked to do the following:

Use a suitable library function out of the set of libraries installed with the .NET platform. You must not use the C# WebBrowser class but perform the required HTTP-level communication directly from within your code. The code must clearly identify the HTTP-level client-server communication and must explicitly manage Home page, Favourite, History Lists and Tabs. 
Optionally, you may add functionality to render a web page, but there must be an option to disable this functionality and to show only the raw HTML that has been retrieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What have you attempted so far and what problem are you encountering?
Maybe [read this first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Currently it sounds like you have been given an [interview or homework task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) that you dont know how to solve. If so, then you should have *some* idea on where to start or you are in the wrong course or job interview. If you want help, then try to solve the question yourself and ask for help when you are stuck. Tell us what you have tried, show the code you currently have and let us know where you are stuck or what doesnt work as expected.

Where are you stuck? Fetching the webpage? Building the user interface?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Here I don't understand how to fetch and render the web page within my tab control without using web browser control.

Comment: A good place to start would be here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx Basically, use the HttpClient to GET the url. (or use the WebClient) Then process the response. The question says: Show the raw HTML wich is simply showing the response. Parsing and rendering the HTML is a whole different story, but this should at least get you started.